# Trim for loop between datapoints from a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, scientific-computing

I loaded a file.dat as a 2d array

```
data = np.loadtxt('file.dat')
```

I have used a for loop as to iterative over all points in this array

```
for i in range(len(data):
```

If I wanted to only do a for loop between points 100-200, how would i do this? I currently have:

```
for i in range(data[100], data[200]):
```

but I get an error

*"TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just specify the range without indexing the data like so:

```
for i in range(100, 201):
```

Comment: Ahh I see, its that simple. I'm not use to python syntax, thanks!